# sending bundle to another activity

Tags: android

I am trying to send a bundle from one activity to another.  When I load the bundle in the recieving activity all the information seems to be null. Here is some code:

Activity A (sending bundle):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(HotelsActivity.this, EditHotelActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b = toBundle(app.getHotelList().get(position));
                intent.putExtra("Hotel Bundle", b);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            });
```

the toBundle method is just adding strings from an object into the bundle. I have put logging statements in this method and the bundle is definately not null.

Activity B (loading the bundle):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.edit_hotel);
        setTitleFromActivityLabel (R.id.title_text);

        // Retrieve sent bundle
        Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        String hotelName = b.getString("hotelname");
        if (hotelName == null)
            MyLog.i(TAG, "IT IS NULL");
    }
```

The loggin statement then prints "IT IS NULL" because for some reason hotelName is null but that is definately the correct key.

Can anyone help with this?

toBundle method:

```
public Bundle toBundle(HotelItem hotel) {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("hotelname",hotel.getHotelName());
        b.putString("hotel address", hotel.getHotelAddress());
        b.putString("hotel telephone", hotel.getHotelTelephone());
        b.putString("hotel website", hotel.getHotelWebsite());


        return b;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use exact key sent:

```
String hotelName = b.getString("hotelname");
```

Updated!

Comment: Hi, I tried that but it is still null.  I thought b.getString("hotelname"); got the key hotelname from the bundle? I added the toBundle method to the original post

Comment: OK, now, make your everything same string `hotelname`, no uppercase, no space, use exact string for the thing called `Hotel Name`

Answer (score 4):

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b = toBundle(app.getHotelList().get(position));
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);




//In your next activity
//Create another Bundle object and get the string by name

Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle!=null){
 String hotelName = bundle.getString("hotelname");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Intent.putExtra(Bundle)` method.

```
 intent.putExtra(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Activity A (sending bundle):
`intent.putExtra("Hotel Bundle", b);`

Activity B (loading the bundle):
`getintent().getExtra("Hotel Bundle");`

not `getintent().getExtra*s*`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using your *toBundle* method, you should `implement` [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html), and write your Object to an `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone still needs this but, in your `intent.putExtra("Hotel Bundle", b);`

It's either you send just `intent.putExtra(b);` so you can get the data via

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String hotelName = b.getString("hotelname");
```

or if you want to keep the `Hotel Bundle` key

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getBundleExtra("Hotel Bundle");
String hotelName = b.getString("hotelname");
```

Sorry, I needed the answer here, so might as well help those who run into this. Cheers.